# How to split string by space and words list

Tags: python, split

Assume that I have below string:

```
"USD Notional Amount: USD 50,000,000.00"
"USD Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount: USD 10,000,000"
"USD Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates: Annually"
"KRW Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates: Annually"
```

Simply, using split function

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["USD Notional Amount: USD 50,000,000.00"
                   ,"USD Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount: USD 10,000,000"
                   ,"USD Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates: Annually"
                   ,"KRW Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates: Annually"])

df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split())
```

[OUTPUT]

```
0    [USD, Notional, Amount:, USD, 50,000,000.00]                 
1    [USD, Fixed, Rate, Payer, Currency, Amount:, USD, 10,000,000]
2    [USD, Fixed, Rate, Payer, Payment, Dates:, Annually]         
3    [KRW, Fixed, Rate, Payer, Payment, Dates:, Annually]
```

I want to have preserving compound words list

```
words_list = ["Notional Amount:","Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount:","Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:"]
```

What I want is to split the string into string array, like below:

```
["USD","Notional Amount:","USD", "50,000,000.00"]
["USD","Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount:","USD","10,000,000"]
["USD","Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:","Annually"]
["KRW","Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:","Annually"]
```

When I split this string I would like to preserve some words as it is not always splitting by space. Anyone knows how to do this kind of string split in Python? Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you describe the pattern? Can you do is so precisely that even someone not knowing the meaning of the words can follow it? Then you should be able to write it in code as well. BTW: This looks like homework, and you showing an effort and a specific problem is mandatory for homework questions!

Comment: Sorry. I added some  code. I mean when I use "split with space  separator", I want to made  to preserve some words  by using wordlist [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xhattam said, there is probably no generic way to do your thing.

However, assuming that you know which strings with spaces you don't want to split, you can do the following (from your example):

```
test = "USD Notional Amount: USD 50,000,000.00"
a = ['Notional Amount:', 'Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount:', 'Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:', 'Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:']

for element in a:
    if element in test:
        # Do this to strip your string from the list
        my_list = test.replace(element, '') 
        # Do this to replace double space by simple space following the word stripping
        my_list = test.replace('  ', ' ')
        # Insert the element you striped in the list at the wanted index
        my_list.insert(1, element)
        break
```

Now you should be able to print my_list and get the following result:

```
print(my_list)
['USD', 'Notional Amount:', 'USD', '50,000,000.00']
```

This is a specific example you can easily adapt to your other strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a generic way to do this, your splits can vary too much, so I'd suggest spending some time on **normalising your input** first (for example, put it in a spreadsheet with the same number of columns for each line) This would really simplify the rest of your process). BUT, here's a way to do it, with your data.

```
st = """USD Notional Amount: USD 50,000,000.00
USD Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount: USD 10,000,000
USD Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates: Annually
KRW Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates: Annually"""

def split_stuff(st):
    res = []
    lines = st.split("\n") # splitting on carriage return
    for line in lines:
        currency, rest = line.split(" ", 1)  # splitting on space, stopping after first space to extract currency (USD, KRW)
        res.append([currency] + [e for e in deal_with_rest(rest)]) 
    return res

def deal_with_rest(rest):
    """ Deals with anything after the (first) currency """
    compound, amt_type = rest.rsplit(" ", 1) # gets the compound and the amt value or type (here, 'annually')
    if compound.strip().endswith("USD"): # if we see there's a currency again, we need to split on it one more time
        return [e for e in compound.rsplit(" ", 1)] + [amt_type] # creating new sublist with compound, currency, and amount
    else:
        return [compound, amt_type] # otherwise, just returning the compound and the amount

for e in split_stuff(st):
    print(e)
```

This returns the following, but only works with your specific string. You'd need to change things of you had more elements in there, or for different currencies for example (I only coded for 'USD' in `deal_with_rest()`):

```
['USD', 'Notional Amount:', 'USD', '50,000,000.00']
['USD', 'Fixed Rate Payer Currency Amount:', 'USD', '10,000,000']
['USD', 'Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:', 'Annually']
['KRW', 'Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:', 'Annually']
```

Answer (score 0):

This generator should do the trick, ':' will be remved from the output though. The return will be tuples. All those artifacts could be changed to comply with your format :)

```
import re

def string_to_accounting(string):
    for line in string.split("\n"):
        a, b = line.split(":")         
        if re.search("[A-Z]{3} ", b): # this could be more strikt if needed
            yield a[:3], a[4:], b[1:4], b[5:]
        else:
            yield a[:3], a[4:], b[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def split_emptynword(string_array):
        for element in wordlist:
            if element in string_array :
                my_list = string_array.replace(element, 'Change').split()
                my_list = [ element if x == 'Change' else x for  x in my_list]
                break
            else:
                my_list = string_array.split()    
        return my_list

    df[0].apply(lambda x: split_emptynword(x))
```

[Output]

```
0    [USD, Notional Amount:, USD, 50,000,000.00]                  
1    [USD, Fixed, Rate, Payer, Currency, Amount:, USD, 10,000,000]
2    [USD, Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:, Annually]             
3    [KRW, Fixed Rate Payer Payment Dates:, Annually]
```

I coded like this, with Arkenys's help. But more good solutions?